# Should I kill Matlab when it is unresponsive?

Tags: windows, matlab

I kicked off a Matlab script several days ago. Usually it takes 5 days to finish. The problem is: I minimized the Matlab command window in task bar, and now I cannot restore it any more. No matter how many times I click on the Matlab window, it does not show up on the screen. Matlab became unresponsive as the result of intensive calculation in my script.
The other programs in Windows still work fine.

As I cannot see the command window, I don't know the progress of my script. It is fine if I know Matlab is till running my script and will finish one day. But I heard from some sources (such as [Fangjun Jiang's answer in a forum](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/157332) except that in my case it does not response for several days, and my code simply contains intensive calculations) that Matlab tried to get out of the freezing before actually doing intensive calculations.

Through Windows Task Manager, I can see that Matlab is using memory (the value of memory used by Matlab changes over time). That is all I can see.

Now my question is: does Matlab still do calculation if its GUI (command window, editor) is unresponsive? I have been running it for many days and it is painful if I kill it without knowing that it is still doing the work >_<

Answer (score 2):

Externally, it is not possible to distinguish between a script which takes long or a script which is stuck in an infinite loop. At this point, I can't give a useful advice, but some suggestions to avoid this in the future:

- Enable the diary. Make sure any error gets printed to console. This way, you have at least a rough idea where it got stuck.
- I would try to separate it into multiple jobs which take the input (matfile) from the previous and produce a new matfile. This way less data gets lost if matlab crashes. Besides matlab sometimes has memory leaks, starting matlab new for each job may solve this.

Comment: In addition to logging the errors to file, I would suggest to also log the progress of your calculation at reasonable intervals. This could be as simple as printing a loop-counter with a time-stamp. In this way, you can see if it is stuck or not.

Comment: Cheers @Daniel, I will try the _diary_ next time. But I can confirm that there is no infinite loop in my code. It just has to deal with huge amount of data. For your idea of multiple jobs, I already did. This script is a sub-script of my big program. It seems stuck at the first intensive command, _svmtrain_. But your suggestion about starting a new matlab is interesting. I will make sure I try it next time

Comment: When I do long running calculations, I like to run a small sample first and then use the big-O complexity to guestimate the time. This also helps in avoiding those calculations that would take way to long.